# Mysql manual migration between RDS machines

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-replication, amazon-rds

I'm trying to migrate my MySQL RDS to a different machine. The reason is that I need smaller disk, and you can't make disks smaller for RDS servers, only bigger.

I'm trying to migrate with this answer: [Backup MySQL Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638012/backup-mysql-amazon-rds#20645291) and this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Start.Repl

Briefly :

Created replica and stopped
Migrated from replica to a new server
Created user on Source DB with:

```
CREATE USER 'repl_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'slavepass';

GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON . TO 'repl'@'%'
```

I've pointed to master from slave with this command:

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('source.mydomain.com', 3306, 'repl_user', 'slavepass', 'mysql-bin-changelog.000001', 107, 0);
```

I've started replication with :

```
CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

When checking status with SHOW SLAVE STATUS, it shows that slave can't connect to master All servers are in the same security group. I was trying to connect to source with repl_user with mysql command line and it worked. I have no idea where to look next. I think it might be something with security in aws, but I was comparing new server with existing replicas and all seems the same.

I'm running MySQL 5.6 on both machines.

Comment: What do your security groups look like for these RDS instances?

Comment: All servers are in the same security group. I have also replicas running within the same groups and also the same availability zone and it's all connecting, also source allows connections from any other machine.

Comment: Allow access to 3306 to that SG.

Comment: SG? If you mean Source DB - 3306 is allowed already. I can connect to this port from any machine...

Comment: Can you share a screenshot showing the security group configuration?

Comment: That will not tell you anything probably, but it's based on custom EC2 Security groups and some CIDR/IP rules for IP addresses. I've tried already to get IP address of Source DB and add it as a CIDR/IP rule to security groups with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work with pointing slave to master IP instead of url, and putting slave ip to inbound rules of Master's security group